# How to connect my web application to SQL Server / SQL Server Express

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2005, jdbc

I am working with a web application that connects to a SQL Server database with this:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1/MyDatabase
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=password
```

I am relatively new to SQL Server, however I have successfully accessed a `SQLEXPRESS` instance through the SQL Server Management Studio.

I can see from the Security->Login folder there is a "sa" entry

However when I run the web application I am getting this error:

> PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property
>   'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (Network error IOException: Connection
>   refused: connect)

I seems that the user: "sa" is not authenticated to access the database?

If so, how can I use the SQL Server management studio to fix this?

Comment: BTW, I tried placing a MySQL JDBC connection instead and my application can connect to the database, however since its just a test, i get error since actual tables that the web application need is not there, so I am pretty sure that the error I get is because I have not set up the user for the database properly.

Comment: have you tried using MS jdbc driver? do you get the same error?

Comment: I think this exception mean that the JVM is unable to communicate with the server at all with the provided URL.

Comment: @JacobTomaw I also thought about it... I will edit my with additional check

Comment: Can you also check what's instance name? If you followed defaults installing Express you have named instance which needs addtional parameter in connect string: [http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#instanceName](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#instanceName)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure authentication mode is set to Mixed. It's set to Windows authentication mode as default which disables sa account. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143705%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Edit: as Jacob suggested, make sure you can connect via TCP/IP (I assume it's used by the driver). To do so launch SQL Management Studio and in connection preferences set: `Authentication - SQL Server authentication`, `login - sa`, `password - your password`. Then click `Options`, `connection properties` and select `tcp/ip` as protocol. Check if you can login.

Answer (score 0):

Also check these things:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909712(v=vs.90).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909725(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

To check whether TCP/IP is enabled and the port is not blocked you can use "telnet  1433". Until telnet doesn't connect, jTDS won't either.

```
e.g, c:>telnet servername 1433
```

to enable telnet client on windows

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/910.how-to-enable-telnet-client-in-windows-7.aspx

Comment: I moved away for SQL already, using NoSQL now, but thanks for the additional answer